# Community Name: Force.com Stack Exchange vs Salesforce Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I often have heard Senior Devs complain that Salesforce fails to seperate the Force.com from the Salesforce/ Sales cloud.

Since the majority of the questions posted here are about development on the Force.com platform (as opposed to functionality offered by each "cloud") would it be beneficial to change the community name to Force.com Stack Exchange?

Just a question from a nooblet.

Comment: Majority yes it relates to dev but i have seen questions related to marketing cloud ,analytic cloud ,communities ,process builder ,reports ,Heroku and others .So little hesitant to make it Force.com Stackexchange .Also salesforce calls force.com as App cloud now .

Comment: App Cloud, they have been doing a lot of name changing recently. Causing me head aches when I explain the platform to higher ups. Well if it is no longer Force.com, the name is better off as SFSE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**No**, is what I'd say. Agreeing with Mohith's comment on the question.

Our focus is anything salesforce. Not just code development and not just the core platform (however their marketing team labels it or will label it in the future).

Also: We're already established as salesforce.stackexchange /SFSE /SSE as a 'brand', some folks may lose track of us if we change that.

Fun fact: the marketing cloud dev [page](https://code.exacttarget.com/)/community links directly to SFSE rather than any salesforce boards. So we're pretty much their 'official' developer community too.

Comment: I'd agree that the scope is wider than just the Force.com platform so we should really stick with an established brand even if Salesforce are having fun shuffling names around on their products.

Answer (score 8):

I would say that Salesforce is better from a search indexing perspective, since when I google an issue I generally append "Salesforce" to the question not "force.com" and I also think that Salesforce is more recognizable to people who aren't familiar with the platform.